# Azure SQL Server & Yii Active Record

Tags: php, activerecord, azure, yii, azure-sql-database

I have an SQL Database in Windows Azure and Yii app on local machine. I use PHP 5.4.9 and `php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll` driver.

Main.php:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=tcp:MYSERVER.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MYDB;',
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
```

When I trying to connect to SQL Server Yii throws this exception:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'sys.extended_properties'.. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT t1.*, columnproperty(object_id(t1.table_schema+'.'+t1.table_name), t1.column_name, 'IsIdentity') AS IsIdentity, CONVERT(VARCHAR, t2.value) AS Comment FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[COLUMNS] AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties AS t2 ON t1.ORDINAL_POSITION = t2.minor_id AND object_name(t2.major_id) = t1.TABLE_NAME AND t2.class=1 AND t2.class_desc='OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' AND t2.name='MS_Description' WHERE t1.TABLE_NAME='users' AND t1.TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'
```

It displays in Gii or on page with simple `<?php echo User::model()->findAllByPk(1)->email;?>` string.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:** User.php

```
class User extends CActiveRecord {
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('email, password', 'required')
        );
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'email' => 'Email'
        );
    }
}
```

Table `users` contains only `id`, `email` and `password` fields.

This code works!

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('regs@kamenskynik.name', 'example')";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$some = $command->execute();
```

How to use SQLSRV with Yii Active Record?

Comment: What is your statement that failed?

Comment: It tells you in the error message exactly what the problem is. Try taking the SQL statement generated in the error and figure out what is wrong with it. Says it doesn't like `sys.extended_properties` which you are trying to join to. I high doubt you have a table named `sys.extended_properties`.

Comment: `<?php echo User::model()->findAllByPk(1)->email;?>` for example.

Comment: @Pitchinnate it's default Yii method. It works with mysql. Why it doesn't work with SQL Server?

Comment: I think it has something to do with your relation you created on the model can you display your relation array for the `User` model?

Comment: No-no-no. I see this exception on Gii page, when it try to get the table structure for creating model or controller or something else...

Comment: Are you sure your connection string and database credentials are correct?

Comment: Yes. I've copied it from Azure portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/db/schema/mssql/CMssqlSchema.php#L294.

I should write my own scheme for this app.